# Create a review comment for a PR with Github api with error: "pull_request_review_thread.end_commit_oid is not part of the pull request"

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I try to create a review comment for a pull request with Github api in Github action but I get this error: "pull_request_review_thread.end_commit_oid is not part of the pull request"

````
URL:
https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/3/comments
Body:
{"body": "Flutter analyze issue:\n```\n   info • Use 'const' with the constructor to improve performance • lib/home.dart:8:12 • prefer_const_constructors\n```", "commit_id": "bb806dd0b26205e617d6e35c8bc908d22faab", "path": "lib/home.dart", "line": 8, "side": "RIGHT"}
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
{
100   680  100   404  100   276    6[95](https://github.com/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/5998169633/job/16265923679#step:3:109)    475 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1172
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "PullRequestReviewComment",
      "code": "custom",
      "field": "pull_request_review_thread.end_commit_oid",
      "message": "pull_request_review_thread.end_commit_oid is not part of the pull request"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/pulls/comments#create-a-review-comment-for-a-pull-request"
}
````

*OWNER: The account owner of the repository. The name is not case sensitive.
*REPO: The name of the repository without the .git extension. The name is not case sensitive.